# Condition to be given for Option set value in a Drill Down Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, subreport, reportparameter, optionsettype

Hi I have a an option set field named as **Stage** . The schema name for the code is **new_stage** .

The option values for Code field are as follows:

Label -> Mobile - Value -> 1

Label -> Telecom - Value -> 2

Label -> Others - Value -> 3

I have got the Sum of each Option values of Stage in each Columns of a table in a report and trying to pass a parameter in each Sum of the option value to go to a Drill down sub report.

The expression I used to get the sum of each Option set value of a Stage field in each column is **Sum(IIf(Fields!new_StageValue.Value = "1", 1, 0), "DataSet1")** .

In the Action tab of the Option set value's Sum text box, I gave the Sub report which I wanted to and gave the parameters.

I have mapped the From, To and Stage parameters as below:

From - [@From]

To - [@To]

Stage - Expr

where the Expr contains **Sum(IIf(Fields!new_stageValue.Value = "1", 1, 0), "DataSet1")** .

I have passed the Integer parameter as you can see **new_stageValue.Value** and I have set the Integer as the Data Type in the Sub report's Stage parameter.

When I saved and generated the main report, I have got the count. When I clicked the count,it went to the sub report but it did not fetch me the records.

Help me as where I am missing! Thanks in Advance!

1. Main Report:
   [image]
2. Main Report's field's condition expression
   [image]

Comment: You will get a lot more help if you can provide screenshots of your set up.

Comment: Hi @iamdave I have added the screenshot as requested by you.

Comment: What is the value displayed in the `Stage` parameter when you click through to the sub report?  When you substitute this value into your dataset query, does the dataset return the values you expect?